# Magento 1.7.0.2 clear cache

Tags: magento, caching

I have issue clearing Magento cache version 1.7.0.2.

I did all possible Clear cache actions, but js, css , phtml changes did not apply.

Details:

I made changes to `menu.js`, `view.phtml`, `custom.css` and no changes

Cache actions:

- Flush Magento Cache
- Disable all cache from Cache management list
- Flush Javascript/CSS cache
- FTP manually clear /var/cache folder and /var/session

So I'm stuck in here, don't know what else to do??

Also, maybe it is related, i cannot access Magento Connect manager, got redirected to 404 page, i already set permissions 755 Folders 644 files...

Comment: Over a year later, but I have the same issue on 1.7.0.2 - specifically with phtml being cached. Tried the same as above to clear with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the CSS and JS compression in the admin when you test your site. The compressed file will be saved in another directory.

look under **/media/css** and **/media/js** clean both folders. If you are shure that you have edited the correct files.

But i think you have edited the wrong files?

Comment: Thanx for fast reply.
i fell like i'm editing wrong files but unfortunately i'm not...more like uploading to wrong server.
What do you think about another issue with Magento Connect 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

If only all of your steps already completed. Check on your controller & layout.

**is the js and css already added to that layout?**